# Requery JPA Entity field after save, update or flush because of db trigger

Tags: hibernate, jpa, triggers

I have a simple JPA Entity, that have a particular behaviour.
One of his attribute is generated by a database trigger.

So I declared

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 15, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long numberToRead;
```

Now each time we save or update the entity, the trigger is triggered and at this moment we need to read the new value of numberToRead.

Before with HBM file we could do that

```
<property not-null="true" unique="true" length="15" column="numberToRead" type="java.lang.Long" name="numberToRead" generated="insert" insert="false" update="false" />
```

But after a while, I couldn't find a solution to replace this Hibernate behavior with a JPA equivalent.

Any idea ?

I'm trying to use these annotations but nothing work

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "numberToRead_insert_update")
@GenericGenerator(name = "numberToRead_insert_update", strategy = "select")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Generated(INSERT)`, this annotation is defined in `org.hibernate.annotations`.

Or, call `refresh()` explicitly.